# Overriding attributes for inherited fields

Tags: c#

Assume I have a class:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {

   [Attribute1]
   [Attribute2]
   public string Property1 {get; set; }

   [Attribute3]
   [Attribute4]
   public string Property2 {get; set; }
}
```

In the child class, that extends this class I want to add new attributes to the `Property1` and `Property2`, preserving attributes, declared in the parent class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this overriding `Property1` and `Property2`. You obviously need to make them virtual in the base class:

```
class MyAttribute: Attribute {}
class YourAttribute: Attribute {}

class Base
{
    [My]
    public virtual void Foo() {}
}

class Derived: Base 
{
    [Your]
    public override void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

And now `var attributes = typeof(Derived).GetMethod("Foo").GetCustomAttributes();` will return both `MyAttribute` and `YourAttribute` instances of `Derived.Foo`.

Do note that all `GetAttribute` type methods have an overload that lets you specify if you want inherited attributed to be included in the result or not. Default behavior is to include inherited attributes.

Comment: For properties (as in the OP... and for events), the boolean for 'Inherited' is ignored when called via `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`. You have to call `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` instead. Also only attributes that have `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inhertied`=true will be inherited.

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {

   [Attribute1]
   [Attribute2]
   public virtual string Property1 {get; set; }

   [Attribute3]
   [Attribute4]
   public virtual string Property2 {get; set; }
}

class NewClass:MyBaseClass
{
  [Attribute5]
  public override string Property1 {get;set;}

  [Attribute6]
  public override string Property2 {get;set;}
}
```

Ensure, that Attributes 1-4 use inherited = true

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class Attribute1 : Attribute
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if the attribute that you want to inherit is not specified with `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited = false`. For example, inherting the `ObsoleteAttribute` does not work:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {

   [Obsolete]
   public virtual string Property1 {get; set; }

}

class Derived : MyBaseClass
{
    public override string Property1 {get; set;}
}
```

In this example, you get the warning message:

> Member 'Property1' overrides obsolete member 'Property1'. Add the
>   Obsolete attribute to 'Property1'

By default, attributes are set with the `Inherit = True` flag. So if you create a custom attribute, inheritance should work fine.